# Cannot scrape google play reviews by using url "https://play.google.com/store/getreviews" by post request

Tags: python-3.x, post, google-play, review

I tried every code available in internet for scraping google playstore. The url "https://play.google.com/store/getreviews" worked for 1 day. It is not working now. I'm getting 404 error.

Please help

Comment: Apparently, they've stopped using this route. Now, they are using a new route `https://play.google.com/_/PlayStoreUi/data/batchexecute` which returns obfuscated JSON response. Your best bet would be to scrape HTML by loading the complete page by scrolling down & clicking "Show more" button.

Comment: Thank you @Oorja for the info. Would you mind sharing any other way for scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a third-party solution like SerpApi. We handle proxies, solve captchas, and parse all rich structured data for you.

With this API you can retrieve up to 199 reviews per page, and then use `next_page_token` to get the rest.

Example python code for retrieving YouTube reviews (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "SECRET_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google_play_product",
  "store": "apps",
  "gl": "us",
  "product_id": "com.google.android.youtube",
  "all_reviews": "true"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
  "reviews": [
    {
      "title": "Qwerty Jones",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwSQC_a0OIQqkAkzuw8nAxt4vrVBgvkmwoSiEZ3=mo",
      "rating": 3,
      "snippet": "Overall a great app. Lots of videos to see, look at shorts, learn hacks, etc. However, every time I want to go on the app, it says I need to update the game and that it's \"not the current version\". I've done it about 3 times now, and it's starting to get ridiculous. It could just be my device, but try to update me if you have any clue how to fix this. Thanks :)",
      "likes": 586,
      "date": "November 26, 2021"
    },
    {
      "title": "matthew baxter",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJy9NbOSrGscHXhJu8wmwBvR4iD-BiApImKfD2RN=mo",
      "rating": 1,
      "snippet": "App is broken, every video shows no dislikes even after I hit the button. I've tested this with multiple videos and now my recommended is all messed up because of it. The ads are longer than the videos that I'm trying to watch and there is always a second ad after the first one. This app seriously sucks. I would not recommend this app to anyone.",
      "likes": 352,
      "date": "November 28, 2021"
    },
    {
      "title": "Operation Blackout",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjMRxVZafTAmwYA5xtamcfQbp0-rUWFRx_JzQML",
      "rating": 2,
      "snippet": "YouTube used to be great, but now theyve made questionable and arguably stupid decisions that have effectively ruined the platform. For instance, you now have the grand chance of getting 30 seconds of unskipable ad time before the start of a video (or even in the middle of it)! This happens so frequently that its actually a feasible option to buy an ad blocker just for YouTube itself... In correlation with this, YouTube is so sensitive twords the public they decided to remove dislikes. Why????",
      "likes": 370,
      "date": "November 24, 2021"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "serpapi_pagination": {
    "next": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?all_reviews=true&engine=google_play_product&gl=us&hl=en&next_page_token=CpEBCo4BKmgKR_8AwEEujFG0VLQA___-9zuazVT_jmsbmJ6WnsXPz8_Pz8_PxsfJx5vJns3Gxc7FiZLFxsrLysnHx8rIx87Mx8nNzsnLyv_-ECghlTCOpBLShpdQAFoLCZiJujt_EovhEANgmOjCATIiCiAKHmFuZHJvaWRfaGVscGZ1bG5lc3NfcXNjb3JlX3YyYQ&product_id=com.google.android.youtube&store=apps",
    "next_page_token": "CpEBCo4BKmgKR_8AwEEujFG0VLQA___-9zuazVT_jmsbmJ6WnsXPz8_Pz8_PxsfJx5vJns3Gxc7FiZLFxsrLysnHx8rIx87Mx8nNzsnLyv_-ECghlTCOpBLShpdQAFoLCZiJujt_EovhEANgmOjCATIiCiAKHmFuZHJvaWRfaGVscGZ1bG5lc3NfcXNjb3JlX3YyYQ"
  }
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-play-product-api) for more details.

Test the search live on the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_play_product&product_id=com.google.android.youtube&gl=us&store=apps&all_reviews=true).

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*